# Combine two SQL statements with sum

Tags: sql

Two statements need to combine.

```
select INVOICEAMOUNT, itemid 
from MTS_NONPAYMENT

select SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM, ITEMID 
from CUS_GLACCOUNT
```

Common column `itemid`. Each time I try and join, it fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using. Also provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: *Each time I try and join* - well, **show us** those attempts of yours !

Comment: Also if fail tell us why / how.  Give you an error or a wrong result.

Comment: sorry i am new to this

Comment: I'm more concerned that each of your customers has their own GL account. I hope that's just a naming convention. :)

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, you appear to be missing `group by`.  I suspect the following does what you want:

```
select itemid, sum(invoiceamount) as invoiceamount, sum(sum) as sum
from ((select itemid, sum(INVOICEAMOUNT) as invoiceamount, 0 as sum
       from MTS_NONPAYMENT
       group by itemid
      ) union all
      (select itemid, 0, SUM(AMOUNT)
       from CUS_GLACCOUNT 
       group by itemid
      ) 
     ) x
group by itemid;
```

To get unequal values, use:

```
having sum(invoiceamount) <> sum(sum)
```

at the end of the query.

Comment: I will try that

Comment: I have my result set. The invoiceamount and sum should be equal. How can I find which results are not equal?

Comment: @Lmoor . . . Use a `HAVING` clause in the outer query.

Comment: select itemid, sum(invoiceamount) as invoiceamount, sum(sum) as sum 
from ((select itemid, sum(INVOICEAMOUNT) as invoiceamount, 0 as sum
       from MTS_NONPAYMENT
       group by itemid
      ) union all
      (select itemid, 0, SUM(AMOUNT)
       from CUS_GLACCOUNT 
       group by itemid 
      ) 
     ) x
 where invoiceamount != (select SUM(amount) from cus_glaccount) group by itemid    ---- this returned the full result set. I expected to see just the values that were not equal to each other.

Comment: `WHERE` <> `HAVING`.